# CSS make table stick at the edge of a div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, html-table

Given :

```js
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="main-container">    {/* the weather box (left) */}
         <div className="weather-box"></div>  {/* the weather information rectangle (right) */}
           <div className="weather_information">
             <div className="left_column">
               <tr>
                {leftColumnBuilder()}
               </tr>
             </div>
             <div className="right_column">
               <tr>
                {rightColumnBuilder()}
               </tr>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
  )
}

const leftColumnBuilder = () => {
    return (
        <table>
            <React.Fragment>
                <tr>Wind</tr>
                <tr>Pressure</tr>
                <tr>Humidity</tr>
                <tr>Visibility</tr>
            </React.Fragment>
        </table>
    )
}

const rightColumnBuilder = () => {
    return (
        <table>
            <React.Fragment>
                <tr>10 m/s</tr>
                <tr> 100 kPa </tr>
                <tr>20 %</tr>
                <tr>2 Km</tr>
            </React.Fragment>
        </table>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
.main-container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  left: 15vw;
  display: flex;
}

.weather-box {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 30%;
  height: inherit;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
.weather_information .left_column {
  float: left;
  position:absolute;
  text-align: left;

  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;

}

.weather_information .right_column {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: right;
  left: 80%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

with a [JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/py40g9zd/32/),

*I want the rightmost column table to be sticking to the edge of the div container.*

[image]

---

I have tried multiple combinations of `float:left` and `float:right` between the left and right tables class divs, I have also tried changing the display.

I know I can use some manual `left: x %` property, but that would make my app look bad upon resizing I believe. There must be a way to make the table stick at the edge of the div. Does anyone have any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that mockup, there's no need to use `float` and `absolute`, which cause unnecessary problems. I'd sugest you take a look at [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) and [flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout).

I've made a somewhat major refator to the code to use Grid instead of floats/absolutes, and though not complete, I believe its a good start.

Also, you have `tr`s outsite tables, the tables themselves could use some extra tags (`thead`, `tbody`), tr + td, etc, and there's no need to use React.Fragment when you are returning a single parent div.

Finally, this is a bit nit-picking, but keep your css classes consistent, don't mix dashes with underscores.

```js
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="main-container">
             <div className="weather-box"></div>
             <div className="weather-information">
               <div className="left-column">
                  {leftColumnBuilder()}
               </div>
               <div className="right-column">
                  {rightColumnBuilder()}
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
  )
}

const leftColumnBuilder = () => {
    return (
        <div>
                <span>Wind</span>
                <span>Pressure</span>
                <span>Humidity</span>
                <span>Visibility</span>
        </div>
    )
}

const rightColumnBuilder = () => {
    return (
        <div>
                <span>10 m/s</span>
                <span>100 kPa </span>
                <span>20 %</span>
                <span>2 Km</span>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

```css
.main-container {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 60vw;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 7fr;
  grid-template-rows: 50vh;
}

.weather-box {
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.weather-information {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  // padding: 0 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.weather-information .left-column {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.weather-information .right-column {
  text-align: right;
}

.weather-information span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed solution, and no it's not nit-picking, you're right I need to maintain consistency regarding that. Thanks again for all these tips!

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using flexbox like the answer above said, it will save you many headaches in the future.

But in your example, you can just replace `left: 80%` with `right: 2px`, or whatever padding you want it to have, [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxwatjso/2/)